# Stripping Unwanted Characters When Writing To A File

Tags: python, text, strip

I am having some problems with stripping out unwanted characters in Python.
The below code is being fetched from a file (although the \rn\n[]' characters are not included in the file.)

I want to strip out all the unnecessary characters listed above so that I just have the numbers and text and then write these to another file. I have tried many methods such as line.strip but none of them have worked.

Here is how I am writing to the file right now;

```
product = str(product)
f.write(product)
```

And here is the result

```
['34512340', 'Plain Brackets', '0.5\r\n']
```

If anybody could explain in simple terms what I need to add to this to remove the unnecessary characters, I would be very grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#list of lines
lines = ['34512340', '0.5\r\n', 'Plain Brackets'];

#looping through the whole list
for i in range(len(lines)):

    #stripping unwanted characters \n and \r from each line
    lines[i] = lines[i].rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r')

    #printing the line without the unwanted characters
    print lines[i]
```

Output:

```
34512340
0.5
Plain Brackets
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
elements = ['34512340', '0.5\r\n', 'Plain Brackets'];

number_of_elements = len(elements);

for i in xrange(0, number_of_elements):
    elements[i] = elements[i].rstrip('\r\n');  # instead of specific symbols, you can also create a list to filter here
    print elements[i];
```

Comment: The `;` have no purpose here and are terribly un-Pythonic.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this. @UrsaMajor Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: My answer is almost the same as Dot_Py's.

Answer (score 0):

Just for some variation:

```
list(map(lambda x:str(x).rstrip('\r\n'),['34512340', 'Plain Brackets', '0.5\r\n']))
```

I really like using the built in function map when applying logic to all items in a list. Just makes for a single line rather then looping through. Performance wise not sure how it stacks up I've never dealt with lists large enough where this makes a difference so I prefer the one liner.

[Map function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

Map takes a function as one parameter then a list or iteratable type as the second param and applies the function to all items in the list. I passed a lambda function declaration just to make it more concise.